# What kind of parallel cable is this?

Tags: printer, cable

I have an HP LaserJet 4600 and need to order a replacement cable for it. Here is a picture of the port on the printer and the cable is currently in use. I've never seen one of this style before. Can anyone provide the type of port this is or a provide a link to a replacement cable?

[image: HP LJ 4600 port and cable]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a Mini Centronics cable.  Lots of aftermarket ones out there.  Be sure to look for IEEE-1284 on the cable.  Here is a very common one from Startech.

[DB25-MiniCentronics](http://www.startech.com/item/1284DB25-6-ft-IEEE-1284-Printer-Cable-A-C.aspx)

Comment: Never heard of Mini Centronics before, good call!

Answer (score 1):

This is an older cable style, it was commonly known as a "centronics" parrallel cable back in the old days, not sure the IEEE number... Centronics was a printer company.  It has 36 pins, and "typically" you can find a 25 pin on the other end.  Just Google "centronics parallel cable" to find some sources.

Comment: Ummm - I don't think so.  Too small for normal "Centronics" - if the person holding it has "normal" width thumb.

Answer (score 0):

[HP LaserJet 4600 parts](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&taskId=130&prodSeriesId=74301&prodTypeId=18972&objectID=bpl11559#A0)

I think you want the **C2946A** cable.